# Where is a good place to find a good SLA agreement?

Tags: service, sla

I would like to find a website that provides example service level agreements (SLA). Anyone know where I can find good examples?

Comment: BTW, when you say "SLA agreement", you're saying "Service Level Agreement agreement".  So definitely don't use your PIN number at the ATM machine, because you might get the HIV virus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a few resources that should help you out:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc543293.aspx
- [http://www.streetdirectory.com/.../service_level_agreement_sla_boot_camp.html](http://www.streetdirectory.com/travel_guide/2510/computers_and_the_internet/service_level_agreement_sla_boot_camp.html)
- http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Implementing+a+service+level+agreement-a0151090784

Answer (score 1):

SLA Agreement for what? These are generally *specific* documents that refer to specific services you offer your users (or that a supplier offers you) and in the former case are very much custom written based on the business needs and funding (it's no good saying "email is a mission critical system where only 1 hour downtime a month is acceptable" if email system isn't funded at the level needed to provide that).

I say "business" here but SLAs might be different between different parts of the business. Your accountancy department are probably more concerned about the uptime of the accountancy system than the call centre, who on the other hand are probably *very* interested in phone systems.

If you're talking about the latter (SLA where you are the customer, or an "underpinning contract" if this is a service you rely on in order to provide a service to your customers) then this is more generic but generally down to the supplier concerned and specific to them.